Liquibase read timeout doing update from localhost to DB in a docker container while VPN is ON
My setup

WSL1 on Windows10
Ubuntu 20.04
GlobalProtect
Docker Desktop

I have setup a postgresql docker container, and am able to log into the database from local laptop,

But when I try to run Liquibase Update, from my local machine, I always get a read timeout error while VPN is on.
export PGDATABASE=pgadmin
export SCHEMA_NAME=public
export PGUSER=pgadmin
export PGPASSWORD='pgadmin_001'
export PGHOST=127.0.0.1
export PGPORT=25432


If I disable the VPN, then Liquibase Update runs fine from my local machine, and all changesets get executed successfully and deployed into the DB in my docker container.
Anyone ran into similar issue before and got a fix? Thanks

Seems the psql that you are running is inside your WSL instance but Liquibase is running from Windows - so this is not really a liquibase issue but an issue connection to WSL from Windows, as WSL -> WSL is really local and Windows -> WSL relies on Windows networking.
Probably you VPN software is blocking the connections.
You could run liquibase from WSL terminal, then it would work. Or review you vpn software policy that may be blocking it...
